# CanCan is Restricting Found Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm using Cancan, Devise, Rails 3 for my ordering application.

Each user has many companies through agreements. Each company also has many users through agreements.

In my ability model, I have the following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user   
    if user.role? :super
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role? :admin
      can :manage, [User, Company, Order]
    elsif user.role? :tech
      can :manage, [User, Company, Tech]  
    elsif user.role? :customer_admin
      can [:read, :update], User, :id => user.id
      can [:read, :update], Company, :id => user.id  
      can [:read ], Order, :id => user.id            
    end
  end
end
```

When a customer_admin logs in, I've been trying to show them only the companies they're associated with. In the company views, I can see the list of users just fine.

In my companies controller (index), I've tried doing this:

```
 @usercompanies = Company.where(['user_id = ?', current_user.id ])
```

However, this lists the wrong company?!

Am sure this is a silly newbie mistake but would appreciate your help. If you need anything else, let me know.

Comment: ALso, in my answer you do want to keep the line `can [:read, :update], User, :id => user.id` because the User model's id and the current_user id are the same thing. All the other records need to modified per my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add restrictions with cancan very quickly and it was puzzling the first time I had to set it up as well. The documentation for setting this up is [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records). And just as a reference you want to make your index action in your controller look something like this:

```
@usercompanies = Company.accessible_by(current_ability)
```

However in the latest version of the gem this should be done automatically on the index action. I think that you have a mistake in your `abilities.rb` because when you have a record and you assoicate it with a user it usually has a collumn called user_id. You would want to use that like so:

```
can [:read ], Order, :user_id => user.id
```

Since the attribute `id` normally is used as the unique id of the record and not the id of the [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: m Thanks! This is really handy. I can't get it to work for my companies one though because they're related to many users through agreements. How can I phrase this in my abilities.rb??  I tried this       can [:read, :update], Company, :user_id => user.id  but it lists wrong company again. Jx

Comment: If you limit users to seeing agreements they have entered in to then they should only see the companies from that relationship right? Perhaps a better way would be to use a block like https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks maybe some code like `if user.agreements.includes?(agreement)` That would let you check to see if a user had access to it.